# Finding values of quotient and remainders for Gaussian integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gaussian-integers

There is an example copied from [example at page 6 of this](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~jverstra/Gaussian1.pdf), that states example of dividend of $3+2i$, divisor of $-1+3i$, and states that as long as the $N_r \lt N_b$, (with $r$ denoting remainder, $b$ the dividend) can compute by division algorithm non-unique set of values of quotient and remainder. The example has dividend as : $3 + 2i$ with norm = $13$, divisor as : $-1 + 3i$ with norm = $10$, and multiplying the fraction with conjugate of the denominator(divisor) yielding : $\frac{3}{10} + i\frac{-11}{10}$.

The first set of values derived is : $q = -i, r = i$. There is derivation of the first set of values by the ratio of $3/10$ being closer to $0$, & of $-11/10$ being closer to $-1$, leading to quotient of $-i$.

The alternate value set suggested is: $q = 1-i$, $r= 1-2i$, as the norm of remainder $\lt$ than that of divisor.
 $(-1 + 3i)(1-i) + (1-2i) \implies (-1 +4i +4) + (1 -2i) = 3 +2i$.

There is no clue to me how to check for different such quotients. Can I take any quotient for any non prime dividend with $N_a \gt N_b, \text{ with } (a$= dividend), and it will always succeed (as I always expect: $N_r \lt N_b$). So, the first step should be the check of dividend being not a prime. But, how? I mean the check should be $(a+bi)(x+yi) = 3 + 2i$, and its conjugate $(a-bi)(x-yi) = 3 - 2i, \exists a,b,x,y \in \mathbb {Z}$. This should lead to :$$
\begin{align}
& (a+bi)(x+yi) = 3 + 2i  & \  (a-bi)(x-yi) = 3 - 2i \\
& (a^2 + b^2)(x^2 + y^2) =13  \\
\end{align}
$$ which to me leads nowhere, as $13$ cannot be factorized into product of two non-unit factors.

Please tell me where I am wrong, as it is not possible to consider the ratio of $a/b$ to be considered for checking primality. So, what is wrong? Totally confused!

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? You suddenly jump from $N_r\lt N_b $ (correct) to $N_q\lt N_b $ (incorrect) and then worry about "dividend being not a prime" (why?). Maybe, take a step back and imagine those are not Gaussian integers but ordinary integers, you are performing the ordinary integral division, all you care about is not to divide by zero, and *the absolute value of the remainder is smaller than the absolute value of the divisor*. Things are virtually the same here.

Comment: To add, with integral division, we also have ambiguity... What do you get when you divide $-7$ by $3$? You may have quotient $-3$ and remainder $2$, or quotient $-2$ and remainder $-1$. If you are interested in programming, here is an interesting link that shows you this ambiguity: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1907565/8734617.

Comment: @user8734617 Actually, the second one meant the norm of dividend ($a$) being more than that of divisor ($b$). Please see my edited OP. Thanks for the link a lot. If could please help in finding out how the dividend ($a$) is not prime, then would be a great help.

Comment: @user8734617 If please could help in finding out that the dividend is not prime, or I am considering the wrong expression to be considered to be checked for primality. Should it be $a/b$ rather than $a$, as the fraction is to be considered for forming quotient.

Comment: Why do you need to check whether the dividend is prime? This is not a consideration for me when applying the division algorithm.

Comment: @G Tony Jacobs  I felt that there should be some significance of being a prime in Algebraic integers, and so am totally confused. I mean that I drew an analogy with the normal integers.

Comment: When carrying out the division algorithm, how is $31/5$ any different from $32/5$? Where does the fact that $31$ is prime enter into the process?

Comment: @G Tony Jacobs Thanks a lot for removing this lack of intuition.

Comment: Indeed, $3+2i$ is prime in the Gaussian integers, but this doesn't affect what we're doing here. Any algebraic integer is prime if its norm is prime in the rational integers.

Comment: @G Tony Jacobs But, one last on this topic - as I am new to algebraic numbers, what is the significance of primes in algebraic numbers.

Comment: The same as their significance in the rational integers. Primes cannot be factored into smaller elements, and any algebraic integer can be factored into primes. In some rings, including the rational integers and the Gaussian integers, this prime factorization is unique, and in other rings, it is not. Understanding the difference, and how we can work in rings without unique factorization, is..... a lot of fun to study! :)

Comment: @jitender Please forget about primality for now. One step at the time. This is showing you how to divide Gaussian integers with remainder. Later on, the fact that you can do it will give rise to the claim that unique factorisation works for Gaussian integers just as it does for ordinary integers. But that comes later. Let's first learn to walk, then to run. To put it differently, you don't need primality for integral division, but you will need integral division for primality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to check with dividend $5+i$ (norm $26$) and divisor $1+2i$ (norm $5$). First, we carry out the division this way:

$$\frac{5+i}{1+2i}=\frac{5+i}{1+2i}\cdot\frac{1-2i}{1-2i}=\frac{7-9i}{5}=\frac75-\frac95i$$

Now, we have $\frac75$ between $1$ and $2$, and we have $-\frac95$ between $-2$ and $-1$. Thus, in principle, we have four options for $q$: $1-2i, 1-i, 2-2i, 2-i$. Usually, we round to the closest integer quotient, because this guarantees that the remainder will be small enough. It will always be true, though, that at least two of these work, assuming there is a non-zero remainder. In some cases, all four will work.

With this example, the closest quotient is $1-2i$. Since $|\frac75-1|=\frac25$, and $|\frac95-(-2)|=\frac15$, we can calculate $(\frac25)^2+(\frac15)^2=\frac15$, so the remainder will have norm $\frac15$ that of the divisor. Indeed, $5+i=(1-2i)(1+2i)+i$, so the norm of the remainder is $1$.

If we choose the "worst case scenario", and go with $2-i$ as our quotient, then the same calculation leads to $(\frac35)^2+(\frac45)^2=1$, so the remainder in that case will be no smaller than the divisor, so that doesn't work for the division algorithm. The other three options, though, are all good.

Does this help?

Comment: +1 A picture of the appropriate square in the complex plane might help too.

Comment: Indeed, with circles centered at each vertex :)

Answer (score 2):

The idea here is borrowed from the same idea when dividing integers: *the quotient must be close to the "real" (rational) quotient, and this makes the remainder small*.

For example, $7:3=2.333333\ldots $ exactly. You want the quotient to be the *whole* number, so you round it, or truncate it - in effect approximate it with a whole number. Here it is going to be 2 (though 3 is not a bad approximation, either).

However, multiplying back, you don't get 7 back: $2\times 3=6$, or $7=2\times 3+1$, where 1 is the *remainder*. It is small, because the approximation was good. Generally, if you divide $a\in \mathbb Z $ with $b\in \mathbb Z, b\ne 0$, you can always pick a whole $q\in\mathbb Z $ such that $|\frac {a}{b}-q|\lt 1$, where $\frac {a}{b}$ is the "real" (rational) quotient and $q $ is a good approximation (a nearby integer). Thus, $|a-bq|\lt |b|$, and let's now call this number $r=a-bq $ a *remainder*, you will have $a=bq+r $ with $|r|\lt|b|$.

Back to the Gaussian integers... It is just the same as above, except that all the numbers are complex. For example, divide $a=7+3i$ by $2-i$:

$$\frac {7+3i}{2-i}=\frac {(7+3i)(2+i)}{(2-i)(2+i)}=\frac {11+13i}{5}=2.2+2.6i $$

Now, pick one Gaussian integer "close" to this. Make sure the distance (the modulus of the difference) is *less than 1* (as in the real case).

The four Gaussian integers "surrounding" your quotient are: $2+2i, 2+3i, 3+2i$ and $3+3i$. Some may be too far:

- $|(2.2+2.6i)-(2+2i)|=|0.2+0.6i|=\sqrt{0.4}\lt 1$
- $|(2.2+2.6i)-(2+3i)|=|0.2-0.4i|=\sqrt{0.2}\lt 1$
- $|(2.2+2.6i)-(3+2i)|=|-0.8+0.6i|=\color {red}{\sqrt{1}= 1}$
- $|(2.2+2.6i)-(3+3i)|=|-0.8-0.4i|=\sqrt{0.8}\lt 1$

So, $3+2i $ is too far, but the other three are just fine, and *any* of them can serve as a quotient. Pick the first one, for example, and the remainder is $(7+3i)-(2-i)(2+2i)=1+i$ with $|1+i|\lt |2-i|$.

That is pretty much it!

**Note**: throughout I've used the *modulus* of a complex number: $|a+bi|=\sqrt {a^2+b^2}$. In your book, they use the *square* of it, i.e the norm is given as $N (a+bi)=a^2+b^2=|a+bi|^2$. This doesn't change the above logic at all, not even a single bit. However, the norm will later turn out to be more useful than the modulus:

- The norm of a Gaussian integer is itself an integer, and the properties of a Gaussian integer are linked to the properties of its norm.
- The norm can be generalised to other number rings, e.g. to numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt {2}$ ($a,b\in\mathbb Z$), where $N (a+b\sqrt {2})$ can be taken to be $a^2-2b^2$.

Comment: So you mean that there can be maximum number of quotients (& hence the remainders) = # of nearest lattice points (being $4$ for a 2-dimensional lattice in the x-y plane). Also, the maximum of $4$ is reached for a given case, if all the other 4 lattice points are equidistant from that, if not wrong.

Comment: @jitender Correct, although you can wiggle a bit away from the center of the square and still have 4 solutions.